Why do Linux Clang and macOS Clang disagree about long long and int64_t?
I have the following C++ code:
#include <cstdint>
template <typename T> class MyClass;
template <> class MyClass<int64_t> {};
int main() { MyClass<long long> obj; }

Using Clang 16 on my M1 MacBook, this successfully compiles. But using Clang 16 on Linux (either x86 or ARM), this fails to compile, with the following error:
foo.cpp:4:33: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'MyClass<long long>'
int main() { MyClass<long long> obj; }
                                ^
foo.cpp:2:29: note: template is declared here
template <typename T> class MyClass;
                            ^
1 error generated.

I've read the question "long long int vs. long int vs. int64_t in C++" but that thread is talking about comparing different compilers (GCC vs MSVC), whereas in this case it's the same compiler (Clang 16) on the same architecture (64-bit ARM, or 64-bit x86 as mentioned above) but just different operating systems (Linux vs macOS).
Why does macOS allow long long to be used for an int64_t template, while Linux does not?

It's the os ABI that defines data types, not the compiler

@AlanBirtles Would you be willing to expand that into an answer? Specifically, I don't understand what exactly the two operating systems are defining differently here, since the two types are both 64-bit signed integers in all the cases I listed in my question.

hat thread is talking about comparing different compilers on different architectures 32-bit vs 64-bit and different operating systems windows vs linux. There is no msvc on linux, there is no gcc on windows. on the same architecture (64-bit ARM, or 64-bit x86 it's a different architecture and a different operating systems.

@KamilCuk please read my question more closely: as I wrote, I tested on both ARM Linux and x86 Linux and they had the same behavior. The discrepancy I am noting is between ARM Linux and ARM macOS, which are different operating systems but do share an architecture.

I don't believe there is any better place to discuss such than its GitHub repo, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues, especially when you wanted to learn why that happens.

Sure, bottom line I do not know what answer you want for "why". "because it was invented that way". Linux 64-bit most probably uses LP64 everywhere. For OSX you would have to ask Apple, there are some links like https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html where is just states it can use anything. It's also multileyered question, once the data model is something decided on machine level in ABI, in constrast uint64_t is a C abstraction that references type with 64-bit, so it's up to the compiler to decide what it is.

The long long int is based on range.  The int64_t is based on bit-width of the number.    The two don't need to be the same size.  The long long int could be 128 bits wide.

@ThomasMatthews What exactly do you mean by "could be"? Do you mean that, on macOS, Clang is allowed to assume that long long cannot be 128 bits wide, but on Linux, Clang is not allowed to assume that?

Imagine that long and long long are both 64 bits on some system. C++ requires them to be different types for the type system, even if they happen to match at the hardware level. int64_t could be a typedef for either one of those 2 types, but which one do we choose? That's arbitrary, and not every system made the same choice.

@MarcGlisse so to make sure I understand, are you saying that the OS gets to decide what int64_t is a typedef for, and on macOS it's a typedef for long long, but on Linux it's a typedef for long? So if I replaced long long with long in my original example, it would succeed on Linux and fail on macOS?

Also, as a meta comment: why is everyone posting comments rather than answers? Comments are meant to ask for clarification, but I don't see these comments as doing so.

Yes, you got it, although it would be safer to say "this combination of compiler + OS (including libc) + hardware + etc" rather than just "Linux".

@SamEstep -- it's a well-known tradition on this stack to post partial answers as comments. For example, I was going to say that the C++ standard doesn't require int64_t to be a typedef for long long. They might be the same type and they might not. It's up to the compiler implementor.

If everyone had agreed on sizes, we wouldn't have needed the typedefs. Overloading (or specializing) on typedefs is dangerous because you don't know what you get.

Windows and Mac typedef long long int64_t, Linux defines typedef long int64_t. This is not an issue.

@3CxEZiVlQ I did not say it is "an issue", I simply asked why this is the case. It seems like what you wrote in your comment is the answer to this question, so someone should write an answer saying as much (unless this is a duplicate of a preexisting question, in which it should be closed as such).

can you specify which clang you are using on each system... for example, AppleClang and llvm clang are different compilers (that default to different c++ standards..)

@SamEstep:  The long long type only needs to have a range of 64-bits.  If the long long type is 128-bits wide, it still meets the requirements of 64-bits; it exceeds the possible range.  There is also the case where the long long type could be multiple "words" glued together.  For example, the platform could use two 32-bit words to represent the type.

@RichardBarber in both cases I am using LLVM Clang; for instance, on macOS, I ran brew install llvm@16.

@ThomasMatthews sure, but unlike what others have written, that doesn't explain why the code example does compile on macOS.

Run the compilation with -E and/or -P and you'll see whether it's long int or long long. With line info, you can backtrace to the #ifdef used. If it's long int for 64 bit, [AFAICT] it has to be long long with -m32 as long int is 32 bits (LP64 model). It also depends on OS as some files use defined(_WIN32) or defined(__sun__), etc. to determine which to use. I've used my own typedef long long my64 and was going to switch to typedef int64_t my64 until I found the latter required a cast for printf with %lld under linux. It seems that long long always works

What I've always used: https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html (which, IIRC, is decades old, from H/W vendor consortium). But, oops, it doesn't define long long too well. But, if long long was 64 bits in one model, it needed to be defined [eventually] for the other models, so if not 64 bits, then what? AFAICT, eventually, long long crept into everywhere as 64 bits (See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3024/lp64-1/index.html). ISO/C can't make long long into 128 bits without breaking LP64 et. al. (which is where this got decided decades ago, and not by ISO/C)
